# Background of the ListItem is not completele hidden when scrolling up

Tags: android, listview, background, listitem

In my ListView the edge of the ListItem background is still visible,
when scrolling to the top.

It still looks up a little from the top edge.

Is there a solution for this problem?

The ListItem background is added via `android:listSelector`

```
<ListView
    ...
    //yellow background
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
/>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you had yellow as the background of the list divider as well. Check to make sure the logic of the list divider is done correctly.

Comment: No, unfortunately no. The divider is the narrow grey stripe, which you can see on the pic.